# How to create an object of derived class based ctor parameters without exclicitly calling the derived

Tags: c#, design-patterns, creation-pattern

I have simplified my true issue into the following example:

```
namespace Cars    
{    
    public class Program    
    {    
        public static void Main(string[] args)    
        {    
            Car car1 = Car.Create(new Driver(1, "A", License.Private));    
            Car car2 = Car.Create(new Driver(2, "B", License.Truck));    
            Car car3 = Car.Create(new Driver(3, "C", License.Bus));        

            car1.OpenTrunk();    
            car2.AttachWagon();    
            car3.OpenBackDoor();    
        }    
    }     

    enum License { Private, Truck, Bus } 

    public class Driver    
    {    
        public uint ID { get; private set; }    
        public string Name { get; private set; }    
        public License License { get; private set; }

        public Driver(uint id, string name, License license)    
        {    
            ID = id;    
            Name = name;    
            License = license;    
        }    
    }        

    public abstract class Car    
    {    
        protected Driver driver;        

        public Car(Driver driver)    
        {    
            this.driver = driver;    
        }    

        public static Car Create(Driver driver)    
        {    
            switch (driver.License)    
            {    
                License.Private: return new Private(driver);    
                License.Truck: return new Truck(driver);    
                License.Bus: return new Bus(driver);    
            }    
        }    
    }   

    public class Private : Car   
    {    
        public Private(Driver driver) : base(driver) {}

        public void OpenTrunk();
    }     

    public class Truck : Car    
    {    
        public Truck(Driver driver) : base(driver) {}

        public void AttachWagon();    
    }        

    public class Bus : Car    
    {    
        public Bus(Driver driver) : base(driver) {}

        public void OpenBackDoor();    
    }    
}
```

Let's say I have a parent class **Car** from which three classes derives: **Private**, **Truck** and **Bus**.

The constructor of the derived classes receive one parameter of class **Driver**.

The class Driver contain among other properties the property **License**.

Assuming that each driver can have a license only to one of the three types of cars (Private, Truck, Bus).

I want to create a function which will return me an object of one of the derived classes based on the Driver provided to the function.

I want the user of this function to receive an object on which he may call specific functions for each derived class such as `bus1.OpenBackDoor()` or `truck1.AttachWagon()`.

What will be the best way to do so while keeping the general structure of the example code (the Create method may be called differently) ?

Comment: You're looking to implement a factory pattern: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/ This pattern is used to create instances of a type, usually related types, and you can give it a parameter (the driver). The problem here is, if the functions are different, defining it as a common base class cannot provide that functionality. You need to use a common interface. If you don't know in advance which type it will be or inherit from, you can't know what members it has either.

Comment: @LEyahoo 
 You can create a generic method to handle that (specific car functions at least), but need to update your classes a little bit. Do you need an object, based on `Driver` properties or can specify the generic argument to get a car instance

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski, I need information which is kept in the `Driver` object to know which of the derived class's c'tor to use.

Comment: @LEyahoo Than you should use the factory pattern, as comment above says, return the `Car` instance (or common interface) and check that you call the specific method. Because for generic type you have to explicitly define the required type and compile time, something like `var car1 = Car.Create<Private>(new Driver(..)); car1.OpenTrunk();`

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski, thanks. If I'll create a static method in the parent `Car` class which will retrive the desired derived class type, is there an option to provide it to the generic `Create<>` method inside the <> brackets? It is not an elegant way but it will release the user of thouse classes from casting the returned object in order to use specific derived class methods.